# Why mysql_fetch_array outputs multiple duplicate results

Tags: php, mysql

From this simple query, I could not figure out why I am getting the repeated result one in [0] and another in [m_id]. I believe the result from given query must display only two values.

```
$sql="SELECT m.m_id, m.work FROM mun as m WHERE m.mun_id=7 ";
$rslt=mysql_query($sql);
$result=mysql_fetch_array($rslt);
print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => 7
        [m_id] => 7
        [1] => 260
        [work] => 260
    )
```

Can somebody figure me out what I am doing wrong.
Thank you.

Comment: a) **don't** use mysql - it's been deprecated and in PHP7 removed. use mysqli or PDO instead. b) you're not doing something wrong, you're just getting associative *and* numeric indizes. the fix is using [mysql_fetch_assoc](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) instead - but again: *switch to mysqli or PDO*

Comment: Yeah thank you for suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the normal behavior of `mysql_fetch_array`. It provides both numerical and associative indices.

If you want only one of them, use `mysql_fetch_assoc` or `mysql_fetch_row`

```
$result=mysql_fetch_row($rslt);

Array
    (
        [0] => 7
        [1] => 260
    )
```

or

```
$result=mysql_fetch_assoc($rslt);

Array
    (
        [m_id] => 7
        [work] => 260
    )
```

It's also worth mentioning that you can get this behavior using `mysql_fetch_array` by passing a second argument.

```
// same as mysql_fetch_row
$result=mysql_fetch_array($rslt, MYSQL_NUM);
```

and

```
// same as mysql_fetch_assoc
$result=mysql_fetch_array($rslt, MYSQL_ASSOC);
```

More info: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Answer (score 2):

The description of `mysql_fetch_array` is the following:

> array mysql_fetch_array ( resource $result [, int $result_type = MYSQL_BOTH ] )

where the second optional parameter is:

> The type of array that is to be fetched. It's a constant and can take the following values: MYSQL_ASSOC, MYSQL_NUM, and MYSQL_BOTH.

And about return value:

> The type of returned array depends on how result_type is defined. By using MYSQL_BOTH (default), you'll get an array with both associative and number indices. Using MYSQL_ASSOC, you only get associative indices (as mysql_fetch_assoc() works), using MYSQL_NUM, you only get number indices (as mysql_fetch_row() works).

It is cited from http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php.

So, in your case, default `MYSQL_BOTH` was applied. I'm sure that the following must solve:

```
$result=mysql_fetch_array($rslt, MYSQL_ASSOC);
```

or

`$result=mysql_fetch_array($rslt,  MYSQL_NUM)`;